# Quickbooks CustomerQuery with Iterator returning duplicate records

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have a strange issue, and I am not sure where the error is

I am working on C#, and while running a query with filters against the Customer object, I get a strange series of results

If the filter I set should return 8 records, then my implementation returns 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 1 records (in that order, in every subsequent call, and all those are duplicate)...

This is how I implemented the Iterator

```
var customerQuery = new CustomerQuery()
            {
                ChunkSize = "8",
                Item = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),

                IncludeFinancialIndicator = false,
                IncludeFinancialIndicatorSpecified = true,
                MinimumBalanceSpecified = true,
                MinimumBalance = 92,
                SynchronizedFilterSpecified = true,
                SynchronizedFilter = SynchronizedFilterEnumType.Synchronized,

             };
        var results = new List<Customer>();
        int count;
        //Loop until find all the results.
        do
        {
            IEnumerable<Customer> partialResult = customerQuery.ExecuteQuery<Customer>(context);
            count = partialResult.Count();
            //First pass here returns 8 records
            //Second pass returns same 8 records again
            //third pass returns 3 records
            //Three more passes with 1 record each

            results.AddRange(partialResult);
        } while (count > 0);
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing anything?

Thanks!

Edit:

this is the code implementing the Paging option....

```
var customerSet = new List<Customer>();
        List<Customer> customerQueryResult = null;
        int startPage = 1;
        var qbdCustomerQuery = new CustomerQuery();
        do
        {
            qbdCustomerQuery.ChunkSize = "10";
            qbdCustomerQuery.MinimumBalanceSpecified = true;
            qbdCustomerQuery.MinimumBalance = 92;
            qbdCustomerQuery.ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType4.StartPage;
            qbdCustomerQuery.Item = startPage.ToString();
            customerQueryResult = qbdCustomerQuery.ExecuteQuery<Customer>(context).ToList();
            if (customerQueryResult.Count > 0) { customerSet.AddRange(customerQueryResult); }
            startPage++;
        } while (customerQueryResult.Count > 0);
```

If I set ChunkSize to "100" I get the 8 expected records, but when trying to run it with ChunkSize = "10" I get 8,8,1 (duplicate records)

Comment: That is weird.  Do you get the same results when paging through the result set vs iterating?

Comment: Are you sure they are the EXACT same records? Do they have the same Id values? Can you post the request XML and response XML?

Comment: Thanks for taking time for this guys... I got an example code from quickbooks support in order to use paging instead of iterator, it seemed to work (with ChunkSize = 100), but when I changed the size to 10, I got a similar error (8,8,1 instead of 8,8,3,1,1,1)... I have 22 customers, of which 8 comply with the filter condition (MinimumBalance = 92)...
This is the rar with all the requests/responses using the iterator option https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5654637/logs.rar
And this is the log using the paging option
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5654637/logs_paged.rar

Thanks again...

Comment: Hey guys! Any hint on this? I could use some help.. thanks!